Erro no terminal do vscode não reconhece javascript
Estou tentando estudando javascript mais até agora não conseguir configurar o vs code para executar o javascript com code.js. está dando erro no terminal, eu já dei as permissão de privacidade no Shell no meu Pc mais o problema continua, eu também já encaminhei o pach para pasta raiz do code.js mais o problema persiste. Alguem por favor me ajudar.

Você vai no ícone da baratinha (ícone do debug), clica em "Abrir um arquivo que pode ser depurado ou executado" para poder altera o seu launch.json. Aí, ao abrir o launch.json, você adiciona o seguinte código abaixo:
{
// Use o IntelliSense para saber mais sobre os atributos possíveis.
// Focalizar para exibir as descrições dos atributos existentes.
// Para obter mais informações, acesse: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Iniciar o Programa",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${file}"
    }
]

}

Quando abrir o lanche.json esse código que você mandou já está lá.
